# Rabbit MQ Strategy to not lose messages

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I have some load balanced web servers that get hit with lots of requests (events).  To keep the web servers very quick I want to push these events into rabbitMq and process them later.

I have a couple questions about the best setup for this.

The initial way I thought about it was have these web servers, publish to a rabbitMq cluster somewhere.  The only problem is that these events are very business critical and we can't afford to lose any (network outages and such).

Is it possible to set up rabbitmq locally on all the web servers, and have the web handlers (IIS) publish these events to the local rabbitmq broker and whenever the 'main' cluster is available the local broker would push them to the main cluster.  Later on the consumers would read the queues from the main cluster and do whatever processing needs to be done.

1. Is this feasibly/easy with RabbitMq?
2. Is this a good way to solve this problem or are there better alternatives?
3. Can I guarantee that no messages will be lost with this strategy?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Federation Plugin: https://www.rabbitmq.com/federation.html

You can have your local RabbitMQ servers, and then federate the messages upstream to another(s) RabbitMQ cluster